# Unable to Split Netmask from Target Expression

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error, subnet, nmap

Why is the following code causing the nmap related error stated in the title? It has to be something syntax related, but I can't figure it out. The range variable is always a subnet (ex. 192.168.1.1/24).

*Unable to Split Netmask from Target Expression*

```
#! /bin/bash

INPUT="/root/testCSV.csv"

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
while read VLAN Range
do
    nmap -v -T4 -Pn --top-ports 200 $Range -oG $VLAN/Results
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Well, for starters check if the file has carriage returns or if has leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: Other than that, paste a sample input from the file that you're trying to parse.